# ORDER BY in a partition - SELECT keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

Please see the DDL below:

```
create table #names (name varchar(20), Gender char(1))
    insert into #names VALUES ('Ian', 'M')
    insert into #names values ('Marie', 'F')
    insert into #names values ('andy', 'F')
    insert into #names values ('karen', 'F')
```

and the SQL below:

```
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) from #names
```

This adds a unique number to each row.  I could also do this (which does not add a unique row):

```
select row_number() over (partition by gender order by (name)) from #names
```

Why do you not need 'SELECT name', however you do not need SELECT null?

Comment: when you partition by gender, you would reset the number back to 1 on Gender value changes in column; what are you trying to do?

Comment: Because `order by [columnname]` is valid syntax, and `order by (expression)` is valid syntax, but `order by (constant expression)` is not.

Comment: You can do `ORDER BY @@SPID` which works the same and saves a bit of typing.

Comment: @MartinSmith hah, sneaky.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: note that this limitation is specific to T-SQL (SQL Server), the SQL standard does allow `order by 1`  in a window definition

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Doesn't that mean "order by the first column" rather than "order by literal 1"?

Comment: @Luaan: no, that is always a constant. Column indexes are not allowed (actually the SQL standard also permits a completely empty window: `row_number() over ()`)

Comment: What is the question here? Why can you not use a sub-query in an order by clause? Also your two examples give two different results, to me, you need to add a partition to your first to get the same values.

Comment: Agreed. What is the question? If you just want to add row number without ordering, instead order by (select null), order by 1 will also do the same. There are many shortcut in tsql as it is a very flexible language. As you gain experience in tsql programming , youtube can do many things not available in others sql language. But be carefull tough, as you might loose your way in standar ansi sql :)

Comment: @cronos2546, as stated in the OP: Why do you not need 'SELECT name', however you do not need SELECT null? Why did you answer the question if you do not understand it?

Comment: @Henry Eko, see comment above.

Comment: He he. Dont get so jumpy. gordon linoff and @cronos2546 has given hints on what happens. The sql execution plan really is your friend when tracing query. Has you try it? Tsql has many shortcut. Just as using (integer + 0.0) to cast the integer as float.

Comment: @Henry Eko, did not mean to sound confrontational.  I am grateful for everyone's comments and answers.  Just wandered if I could clarify anything.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, this is just a quirk of SQL Server.  SQL Server does not permit constants in `ORDER BY` (nor in `GROUP BY`, which can occur in other contexts).

Probably the origin of this is the `ORDER BY` clause in a `SELECT` statement:

```
ORDER BY 1
```

where "1" is a column reference rather than a constant.  To prevent confusion, (I am guessing), the designers of the language do not allow other constants there.  After all, would `ORDER BY 2 + 1` refer to the third column?  To the sum of the values in the two columns?  To the constant 3?

I think this was just carried over into the windows syntax.  There is a way around it -- as you have seen -- by using a subquery.  The following should also work:

```
ROW_NUMBER() ORDER BY (CASE WHEN NAME = NULL THEN 'Never Happens' ELSE 'Always' END)
```

Because a column is mentioned, this is permitted.  But, `= NULL` never returns true, so a constant is used for the sorting.  I use the `SELECT NULL` subquery, however.

Answer (score 1):

The Order By clause has 4 basic syntax structures.

1. Specifying a single column defined in the select list
2. Specifying a column that is not defined in the select list
3. Specifying an alias as the sort column
4. Specifying an expression as the sort column

You can review the MSDN documentation here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx

I believe that your SELECT NULL, or really any constant that you want to specify in your order by clause, would require the select because the database engine is evaluating the constant as a #4 structure, an expression. As proof, in my query example, I have used a COUNT(*) in lieu of your select null.

I believe when you specify Name or Group in your order by clause, you are actually using a different order by structure, possibly #1. Here is my proof from the execution plan and results of your corrected first and original second query's sort operation. I have removed the partition because it's not relevant to our discussion.

```
select row_number() over (order by (select null)),name from #names

select row_number() over (order by name),name from #names

select row_number() over (order by Gender),name from #names
```

I have attached the execution plans for the three queries.
[image: Execution Plans]

As you can see, no Sort Operation is performed on the data that is passed to the Segment operator which handles the window function. This is mirrored in the results of these queries, also pictured below.

[image: Results]

So basically, SQL Server just ignored or did not operate on your Order By clause sub-query, because it could not associate the values which you returned in the sub-query to a particular parent column using method #4 and the reason that you do not specify "SELECT name" in your Order By sub-query is because you are actually using a different Order By syntax structure.